# Tk::MListbox doesn't expand

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I would like to create a Tk application with a MListbox to display some data. If there is too much information, I would like that a scrollbar appears.

My problem is that the MListbox doesn't fill all the available space. There is a blank space on the right. It doesn't look very nice.
Is it possible to solve this problem? Or should I use another widget? (TableMatrix seems interesting but I can't download it). I chose MLlistbox because I want to be able to hide some columns and change the size of each column.

This is the code I had so far:

```
my $frameDocuments = $mw->Frame(-background => '#CCCCFF');
    $documentsListbox = $frameDocuments->Scrolled(
        'MListbox',
        -scrollbars => 'osoe',
        -columns => [
                        [-text => 'Name'], [-text => 'Path'], [-text => 'Format'], 
                        [-text => 'Loader Type'], [-text => 'Cache directory']
                    ],
        -resizeable => 1,
        -moveable => 1,
        -sortable => 1,
        -selectmode => 'browse',
    );

$frameDocuments->pack(-anchor => "n",-expand => "1",-fill => "both",-side => "top");
    $documentsListbox->pack(-anchor => "n",-expand => "1",-fill => "both",-side => "top");
```

Comment: As a workaround you can try use `$documentsListbox->columnPack(@ar)`, where `@ar` contains the sizes of the columns. Since you have 5 columns you could try make each 1/5th of the screen-width, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the [`Tk::MListbox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::MListbox) does not resize its own columns when the window width becomes larger than the sum of the column widths. Seems like a bug, maybe you should report it?

Anyway, you can try work around it by using `columnPack` function. According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tk::MListbox):

> **$ml->columnPack(array)**
>
> Repacks all columns in the MListbox widget
>   according to the specification in array. Each element in array is a
>   string on the format index:width. index is a column index, width
>   defines the columns width in pixels (may be omitted). The columns are
>   packed left to right in the order specified by by array. Columns not
>   specified in array will be hidden.

Here is an example<sup>1</sup> where I maximize the window to fill the whole screen, and then compute the column widths:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;
use Tk::MListbox;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
my $frameDocuments = $mw->Frame(-background => '#CCCCFF');
my @columns = (
    [-text => 'Name'],
    [-text => 'Path'],
    [-text => 'Format'], 
    [-text => 'Loader Type'],
    [-text => 'Cache directory']
);
my $numCols = scalar @columns;

my $documentsListbox = $frameDocuments->Scrolled(
    'MListbox',
    -scrollbars => 'osoe',
    -columns    => \@columns,
    -resizeable => 1,
    -moveable   => 1,
    -sortable   => 1,
    -selectmode => 'browse',
);

$frameDocuments->pack(
    -anchor => "n",
    -expand => "1",
    -fill   => "both",
    -side => "top"
);
$documentsListbox->pack(
    -anchor => "n",
    -expand => "1",
    -fill => "both",
    -side => "top"
);

my $screenHeight = $mw->screenheight;
my $screenWidth = $mw->screenwidth;
$mw->geometry( sprintf "%dx%d+0+0", $screenWidth, $screenHeight );
my $colWidth = int( $screenWidth / $numCols );
my @ar = map { "$_:$colWidth" } 0 .. ($numCols - 1);
$documentsListbox->columnPack(@ar);

MainLoop;
```

**Resulting window**:

[image]

**Footnotes**:

1. I used *camelCase* for variable names in the code snippet since you already used it in your question. Note that *snake_case* is more common in Perl.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: It is too bad that it doesn't expand automatically. I will then use your solution. I will have to bind to the window size modification if I want to be able to extend the window. Or maybe I will simply forbid window modification. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it is a pitty. Maybe you could check the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/RCS/Tk-MListbox-1.11/MListbox.pm) and suggest an improvement to the author (if he is still around then since it seems like 15 years ago he last updated anything).. But binding to the the configure event as you say, should also let you manually do the update of the list box columns as you desire